# Can we train specific part of tensor with tebnsorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, tensor, adversarial-machines

I am trying to make an adversarial image for the inceptionV3 model with tensorflow. For that I use a specific loss on the pixel of my input image. This works well

```
model_input_layer = model.layers[0].input
model_output_layer = model.layers[-1].output

cost_function = model_output_layer[0, object_type_to_fake]
gradient_function = K.gradients(cost_function, model_input_layer)[0]
grab_cost_and_gradients_from_model = K.function([model_input_layer, K.learning_phase()], [cost_function, gradient_function])
```

Now I would like to make only certain pixels trainable to create a patch on a certain square and not on the all input image.
I have tried to use `variable = tf.slice(model_input_layer, [0, 100, 100, 0], [-1, 100, 100, -1])` but it does not work.
Does anyone has already done this ?

Comment: Try `var = tf.Variable(tf.slice(model_input_layer, [0, 100, 100, 0], [-1, 100, 100, -1]))`?

Comment: Thank you for your answer but unfortunately it does not work. I tried `var = tf.Variable(tf.slice(model_input_layer, [0, 100, 100, 0], [-1, 100, 100, -1]), validate_shape=False)` but then the `K.gradient` method returns `None`.